# Angular controller not printing variables to view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, view, controller

Angular controller is not talking to view. ng-app is included, and also is ng-controller.

Using meanJS.

Here is the view:

```
<section ng-app="my-module" ng-controller="MyModuleController">
  <div>
    {{ costumers[0] }}
  </div>
</section>
```

Here is the controller:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('my-module')
    .controller('MyModuleController', MyModuleController);

  MyModuleController.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function MyModuleController($scope) {
    var vm = this;

    // My module controller logic
    // ...

    $scope.costumers = [{
      name: 'John Doe',
      city: 'New York'
    }, {
      name: 'Peter Griffin',
      city: 'San Francisco'
    }];

    init();

    function init() {

    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: anything in Browser console?

Comment: Can you see the right HTML?

Comment: @Mr.Arjun angular.js:11706 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MymoduleController' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: If it is not existing App then `module('my-module',[])`

Comment: @Michelem what do you mean?

Comment: Try this `angular.module('my-module',[])` for creating a new module. If your module is already created with name `my-module` then you can use `module('my-module')`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `vm` instead the `$scope`:

```
function MyModuleController($scope) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.costumers = [{
      name: 'John Doe',
      city: 'New York'
    }, {
      name: 'Peter Griffin',
      city: 'San Francisco'
    }];

    init();

    function init() {

    }
  }
```

HTML:

```
<section ng-app="my-module" ng-controller="MyModuleController as vm">
  <div>
    {{ vm.costumers[0] }}
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: So you have other problems

Comment: Sorry I forgot you need to change also this: `<section ng-app="my-module" ng-controller="MyModuleController as vm">`

Answer (score 0):

After loosing a few hair, i've solved the problem. The problem was in routing file, a simple misspelling in controller's name. "Argument 'MymoduleController' is not a function, got undefined" listed at the browser console, shows that it is spelled wrong. It was intended to be MyModuleController, not MymoduleController. Thanks for the help guys, problem solved!

Here is the fixed routing file:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  //Setting up route
  angular
    .module('my-module')
    .config(routeConfig);

  routeConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];

  function routeConfig($stateProvider) {
    // My module state routing
    $stateProvider
      .state('my-module', {
        url: '/my-module',
        templateUrl: 'modules/my-module/client/views/my-module.client.view.html',
        controller: 'MyModuleController',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
      });
  }
})();
```